# Disease-Symptom relation in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I am making an electronic health system related to patient diagnosing in PHP and MySQL. I have made following tables in database with the following records:

```
Illness(illness_id(PK), illness_code,illness_name)
Symptom(symptom_id, illness_id(FK),symptom_name ).
```

Now, what I would like to do is that, I will write name of symptom in search bar and after clicking button, related diseases should be output. Could you tell me SQL query that will output appropriate diseases please?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Please include what you have tried in your question.

Comment: @PradnyaBolli: please only use inline code formatting (backticks) for formatting code or console i/o. Technologies such as MySQL are just proper nouns, and so capitalisation is perfectly adequate.

Comment: Your question is back to front.  You need to ask the general question first, and then work out how to do it.  Your database structure is inadequate to support what you are trying to request of it.

Comment: I thought  by means of id_symptom foreign key I could make a connection between symptom and  disease. Could you give your own suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. After you retrieve the symptom value from the search bar into a variable, say symptom_name_provided_in_search_bar, you can use that value in the below query

```
select illness_name
from   illness a, symptom b
where  a.illness_id = b.illness_id
and    b.symptom_name = :symptom_name_provided_in_search_bar
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you should create only one table illness with 2 rows:
illnessName and illnessSymptom. Note: This will only work if the symptom is written exactly as in the database.

```
<?php
$host = 'yourmysqlhost';
$user = 'yourmysqluser';
$pass = 'yourmysqlpassword';
$db = 'yourmysqldatabase';
$symptom = $_POST['symptom'];
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$sanitizedSymptom = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $symptom);
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM illness WHERE illnessSymptom = '".$sanitizedSymptom."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0)
{
echo '<p>No results...</p>';
}
else
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
echo '<h1>'.$row['illnessName'].'</h1>';
echo '<p>Symptom: '.$row['illnessSymptom'].'</p>';
echo '<br>';
}
}
?>
```

## Edit:

To find a symptom that is approximately like the symptom in the database, the query should be like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM illness WHERE illnessSymptom LIKE '%".$sanitizedSymptom."%'");
```